# How do I interpret the units from object.size?

Tags: r

The documentation of `object.size` suggests that it can accept either "MB" or "Mb" as arguments to `format`.  I understand that "B" is the abbreviation for byte and "b" for bit.  However, when I call the `format` function with these two inputs, I get the same result.  And this result has units of "b".

Is it respecting the distinction between bits and bytes?  Or should I interpret all results as bytes despite the lower case "b"?

```r
x <- runif(1e6)
format(object.size(x), "Mb")
#> [1] "7.6 Mb"
format(object.size(x), "MB")
#> [1] "7.6 Mb"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: There are some details on the `?format.object_size` help page, but in this case both "B" and "b" are interpreted as bytes. There's no built in formatting for the number of bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the formatting part in the documentation you'll see that the default formatting is done in bytes.

> the byte-size unit standard to be used. A character string, possibly abbreviated from "legacy", "IEC", "SI" and "auto". See ‘Formatting and printing object sizes’ for details.

Also if you try:

```
> print(object.size(x))
8000048 bytes
```

where this equals roughly to 7.6 MB.

Comment: Thanks.  I can produce the desired result with `format(object.size(x), units = "MB", standard = "SI")`